# Laravel eloquent orderByRaw error with two withCount() value

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

-Likes table migration:

```php
public function up()
  {
      Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->id();
          $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
          $table->boolean('direction');
          $table->morphs('likeable');
          $table->timestamps();
      });
      Schema::table('likes', function ($table) {
          $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
      });
  }
```

Like model:

```php
    public function likeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

In Entry model:

```php
    public function likes(): morphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable')->where('direction', true);
    }

    public function dislikes(): morphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable')->where('direction', false);
    }

    public function likesAndDislikes(): morphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable');
    }
```

I run this query:

```php
Entry::withCount(['likes', 'dislikes'])
        ->orderByRaw('(likes_count + (dislikes_count * -1)) desc')
        ->paginate();
```

I got error:

> quote
> Illuminate\Database\ QueryException
> PHP 8.1.3
> 9.45.1
> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "likes_count" does not exist LINE 1: ... $4) as "dislikes_count" from "entries" order by (likes_coun... ^
> SELECT
> "entries".*,
> (
> SELECT
> count(*)
> FROM
> "likes"
> WHERE
> "entries"."id" = "likes"."likeable_id"
> AND "likes"."likeable_type" = entries
> AND "direction" = 1
> ) AS "likes_count",
> (
> SELECT
> count(*)
> FROM
> "likes"
> WHERE
> "entries"."id" = "likes"."likeable_id"
> AND "likes"."likeable_type" = entries
> AND "direction" = 0
> ) AS "dislikes_count"
> FROM
> "entries"
> ORDER BY
> (likes_count + (dislikes_count * -1)) DESC
> limit
> 15 OFFSET 0

Comment: Even in eloquent you can't use aliased

Comment: I follow this topic and tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225255/how-to-multiple-withcount-columns-sum-and-order-by-in-laravel . Do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: And it is work with mysql. I cant run with pgsql @nbk

Comment: MySQL is very different from posrgres, so search for aliasrs in order by

Comment: @nbk yes they are different. But here is a ORM.

Comment: That doesn't matter postgres can not use aliases , you need to repeat the query or look for with clause